# Import conda error traceback upon opening terminal

Tags: conda, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-terminal

The below lines of code show up every time I open my terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named conda
```

I am worried I have possibly corrupted my (base) conda environment but I haven't run into any issues so far. Mainly, it's just really annoying to see.

Using `conda activate base` gives no errors. All I was doing as of recently was removing and reinstalling different versions of opencv so that I would have a version that allows me to use imshow(). I also did `path_to_env_python -m pip3 install common`. Besides that I don't think I have done anything that would cause the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like an issue introduced with conda `4.8.0`. Better revert conda to `4.7.12` for now, this one is stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the same issue. For me a temporary fix was commenting out the eval and its else if loop in bashrc.

There is a thread on this issue on the github of conda:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9505

edit: It was an error in 4.8.0 anaconda. In `<conda_install>/etc/bash_completion.d/conda` python was called without adding the path towards the anaconda python, with as a result that it opened python 2.7 and then tried to import conda. It has been fixed by the most recent update, so running `conda update conda` should fix the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to an upstream issue since I am facing the same problem since this morning on two different machines. So I would suggest to not modify your RC files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
The reason is in .bashrc:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/myname/app/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/myname/app/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/myname/app/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/myname/app/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

Problematic line:

```
eval "$__conda_setup"
```

Solved by replacing the whole block with:

```
export PATH="/home/myname/app/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Did you look any deeper into why it failed? Manually manipulating `PATH` in interactive sessions is strongly discouraged because it ends up leaking the **base** env into others that one might activate.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution breaks working ```conda activate``` from terminal

Comment: Working solution provided here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9505

Answer (score 0):

The error has been fixed, you need to do a `conda update conda` in your terminal and it will work like a charm.