# ImportError: No module named conda

Tags: conda, miniconda

I have a problem with conda. When I open the terminal (I am using Ubuntu 18) I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 3, in
>    ImportError: No module named conda

Conda commands and python are working perfectly, but I want to get rid of that message.
This was not happening before, so I removed conda and installed it again. However, the problem persist. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import conda error traceback upon opening terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317257/import-conda-error-traceback-upon-opening-terminal). There is a currently an issue with Conda v4.8.0 that is a likely cause of this. Please include your Conda version in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it by exporting miniconda path just before the "conda initialize"
block added during installation in my .bashrc file.
I do not understand why now works. If anyone could give a reason I will be glad.